# Can't get color image with Camera1394

Tags: ros, monocular-camera, camera1394

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I can get nice grayscale image but not color image. Coriander only gives me mono format, but the camera is videre color camera. Even dynamic_reconfigure GUI can just be set to mono format.

Any ideas?

P.S. I have also checked videre_stereo_cam. But videre_stereo_cam can't support monocular camera. So I think camera1394 is the only choice.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/41158/can%27t-get-color-image-with-camera1394/) by [LeonInTexas](https://answers.ros.org/users/2961/leonintexas/) on ROS Answers with karma: 5 on 2012-08-10

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) on 2012-08-10**:
What model camera are you using?

**Comment by [LeonInTexas](https://answers.ros.org/users/2961/leonintexas/) on 2012-08-11**:
Model No. STH-DCSG-VAR, color Serial No. 3281

**Comment by [Ryan](https://answers.ros.org/users/195/ryan/) on 2012-08-21**:
Have you been able to use the debayer option in Coriander? The camera might be outputting Bayer pixels.

**Comment by [LeonInTexas](https://answers.ros.org/users/2961/leonintexas/) on 2012-08-23**:
Thanks, Ryan. I tried Bayer option and it works!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Have you ever tried the SVS library? I have the same model camera you do, except mounted as a stereo pair. I couldn't use videre_stereo_cam, so I started my own ROS node based on SVS to access images and other info from the camera. So far it's going well and I am able to publish images in ROS. If you have access to SVS (it was usually shipped with those cameras) then perhaps you could use some of my code.

---

Originally posted by [georgebrindeiro](https://answers.ros.org/users/2573/georgebrindeiro/) with karma: 1264 on 2012-08-21

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1